# The definition of Time Invariant systems

Tags: signal-analysis, system-identification

according to the wikipedia [Time-invariant system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system) article:
Mathematically speaking, "time-invariance" of a system is the following property:[4]: p. 50

> Mathematically speaking, "time-invariance" of a system is the following property⁴:
>
> > Given a system with a time-dependent output function $y(t)$, and a time-dependent input function $x(t);$ the system will be considered time-invariant if a time-delay on the input $x(t + \delta)$ directly equates to a time-delay of the output $y(t + \delta)$ function. For example, if time $t$ is "elapsed time", then "time-invariance" implies that the relationship between the input function $x(t)$ and the output function $y(t)$ is constant with respect to time $t$:
> >
> > $$y(t) = f( x(t), t ) = f( x(t)).$$
>
> In the language of signal processing, this property can be satisfied if the transfer function of the system is not a direct function of time except as expressed by the input and output.

we can see two(different?) definitions of time invariant systems. the first is a shifting in time of the signal, and the second says that the output if a function ONLY of the input.
are the definitions equal? if one happens it means that the second happens and vice versa?

lets take for example the system: $y(t)=x(t+1)$.

by shifting $x(t+\tau)$ we get TI system, but how can we see that the system if a function of the signal only?

---

⁴ p. 50 of Oppenheim, Willsky: Signals and Systems, 2nd ed, 1997.

Comment: there's no two definitions here? I'm not sure where you're taking that from.

Comment: could you please link to the wikipedia article in question?

Comment: ah, found it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system

Comment: replaced  your picture of text by text, actually linked to the page :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an awkward definition of time invariance. More common is the following one.

A system $y(t) = F(x(t))$ is time invariant if

$$F(x(t-\tau)) = y(t-\tau)$$

In words that means the order of applying the system and time shifting doesn't matter. Time-Shifting and then applying the system OR applying the system and then time shifting give the same result.

> we can see two(different?) definitions of time invariant systems.

Not really. The output signal is always a function of the input signal and the system. If you time shift the input signal, it becomes a different input signal

Comment: We should probably just "fix" the wikipedia article.

Comment: But $y(t) = x(t+1)$ is not a function of $x(t)$, I mean you canno't describe $y(t)$ as $F(x(t))$.

Comment: @mcr0yal $x(t+1) = q x(t)$ where $q$ is the time-domain advance operator. That makes $y(t)$ a function of $x(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Both definitions mean "It doesn't matter what the clock on the wall says, the system always responds the same to an input."

The definition where you're time-shifting both input and output is a *test* that you can perform on a system (either mathematically or in the real world).

The definition that says $f\left(x(t), t \right) = f\left(x(t)\right)$ is a mathematical way of saying "$f\left(x(t), t \right)$ ignores $t$, you can leave it out".  (Note, in my humble opinion it should say $f\left(x(t), t \right) = f\left(x(t)\right)\ \forall\ t \in \mathbb R$, to really drive the point home).